# Is there a Cytoscape Web Application available?

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

[cytoscape]

Is there a fully featured cytoscape web app available? I want my organization to use cystoscape maps but I need a full featured web app to do this.

I have tried to export my graphs to a webpage but I need most of the features of the Cytoscape application in the web application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use cytoscape.js in headless mode together with a web maps (i.e. Leaflet). See example: https://swatchai2020.pythonanywhere.com/init/static/bkk_mts/index.html

Answer (score 0):

At this point, there isn't a full-featured Cytoscape web app.  Efforts are underway to develop a Cytoscape web app, but it will be some time before it has all of the features of the Cytoscape desktop.